# Initialize Guard with value

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

Is it possible to initialize guard with a specifig value ?
For example the current example will not work:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    CoreModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AuthGuard, // while using APP_GUARD works
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
        return new AuthGuard(configService.get('some_key'));
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
    },
  ],
})
```

While using `APP_GUARD` for `provide` will initialise the guard with config value. So it works only for global scope, but not for `@UseGuards(AuthGuard)`

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't work because guards are not registered as providers in a module. They get directly instantiated by the framework.

You can either use dependency injection in the guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyAuthGuard {
  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {
    // use the configService here
  }
}
```

and

```
@UseGuards(MyAuthGuard)
```

or instantiate the guard yourself:

```
@UseGuards(new AuthGuard(configService.get('some_key')))
```

---

In the special case of the `AuthGuard`, you can set a `defaultStrategy` in the `PassportModule`. Then you can just use `@UseGuards(AuthGuard())`

```
PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt'})
```

or async:

```
PassportModule.registerAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({ defaultStrategy: configService.authStrategy}),
  inject: [ConfigService],
})
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answer.
Take a look please on the comment added for Igor. What do you think ?

Comment: Then I would use the `defaultStrategy` as suggested in my answer.

Comment: Still having problems? :-)

Comment: No :)
Thanks for sharing solution!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want your specific guard instance to perform differently depending on some input, basically be able to configure it. There is no option to consume this config from `constructor()`. Factory way might look like a bit bulky solution. But you're still able to utilise static methods to achieve wanted behaviour.

Example:

```
@Injectable()
class SomeController {
  @Get()
  @UseGuard(AuthGuard) // but how to pass smth inside AuthGuard?
  public async doSomething() {}
}
```

Solution:

```
// [auth.guard.ts] file
import { UnauthorizedException, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import type { CanActivate, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import type { GuardOptions, PatchedRequest } from './auth.types';


export interface GuardOptions {
  allowAnonymous?: boolean,
  allowExpired?: boolean,
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard
implements CanActivate {
  public options: GuardOptions = {};
  public canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> {
    // Guard logic 
    return true;
  }

  static configure(options: GuardOptions) {
    const instance = new AuthGuard;
    instance.options = options;
    return instance;
  }
}


// [someEntity.controller.ts] file
// imports...

@Injectable()
class SomeController {
  @Get()
  @UseGuard(AuthGuard.configure({ allowExpired: true })) // voila
  public async doSomething() {}
}
```

Enjoy! Glory to Ukraine!

Answer (score 0):

I would try ht less verbose approach and inject ConfigService directly into the AuthGuard in such a manner:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    CoreModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthGuard,
  ],
  exports: [
    AuthGuard,
  ],
})
```

```
@Injectable()
export default class AuthGuard {
  constructor (protected readonly config: ConfigService) {
  }
  /*
  ...
  */
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answer.
What i am trying to achive is to get rid of configService by initializing it in providers as described, which actually works for global context (using APP_GUARD).
So i won't to understand if it's an issue or not. What do you think ?